# Mongoosastic how to set up term suggester to do full string search

Tags: elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

I'm using completion suggester of ElasticSearch to looking for tags in the database. It works but I'd like to change to term suggester. Because with some tags that have two words like "abc def", if I search "abc", I can find it but I can't with "def". Because the completion suggester works only for prefix search.

How could I use term suggester? I found nothing in the doc of mongoosastic.

This is my code using completion suggester:

```
// create tag model
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic');

var tagSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        es_indexed: true,
        es_analyzer: 'simple',
        es_payloads: true,
        es_type: 'completion',
    }

});

tagSchema.plugin(mongoosastic);

var Tag = mongoose.model('Tag', tagSchema);

// add some data
Tag.createMapping(function(err, mapping) {
    async.each(tags, function(t, done) {
        var newTag = new Tag(t);
        newTag.save(function(err) {
            if (err) { console.log(err); }
            newTag.on('es-indexed', function(err, res) {
                if (err) { console.log(err); }
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});

// looking for some tags with keyword
Tag.search(
    null,
    {
        suggest: {
            "tags-suggest": {
                "text": keyword,
                "term": {
                    "field": "name",
                    "size": 10
                }
            }
        },
        size: 0
    },
    function(err, data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
)
```

Thanks !